# Android VPN prevent out traffic from tun0

Tags: android, vpn, tun

I have crated VPN Client on Android device, When tun0 is created all the traffic is routed vis tun0. I would like to prevent out traffic going via tun0. Please let me know is there a to prevent out traffic via tun0.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to exclude some apps from sending data through your `VpnService`, there is an API for that on the `Builder`.

In your `VpnService`:

```
Builder builder = new Builder();
builder.addAddress(TUNNEL_ADDRESS, 32); // Local address of TUN (?)
```

To exclude specific apps from the VPN use:

```
builder.addDisallowedApplication(packageNameOfExcludedApp);
```